# onMenuItemClick not called

Tags: java, android

I'm working from the [Android demo code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html) for sharing data from my app. This adds a "share" menu to the app. Sharing works fine with the demo code.

I need to prepare the share intent when the user taps on the share icon. Therefore, I added a listener:

```
MenuItem shareMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
sap = (ShareActionProvider) shareMenuItem.getActionProvider();
sap.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

shareMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
    new OnMenuItemClickListener(){
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){   <----- never called
            Log.e("test", "share menu selected");       
            return true;
        }
    }
)
```

Unfortunalely **onMenuItemClick** is not called when I tap on the icon.
What am I missing ?

I have looked into using **onShareTargetSelected** but modifying the intent there is not allowed. I am currenly preparing the intent in **onPause()** but it slows things down (Bitmap operations) when I move to unrelated activities in my app.

Comment: Isn't that event dispatched to the Menu instead of the individual MenuItems? What happens when you set the listener on the Menu itself? Also, why not use Activity.onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)?

Comment: I tried it (forgot to mention it). onOptionsItemSelected is not called for this menu. It is called for the other menus.

Comment: I know. Sorry, I'm a bit confused ;)

Comment: No problem ! I'm confused too !

Comment: So just to get this straight: the Menu shows, but when you click "Share" (or whatever it's called) nothing happens? How is the Menu registered with the Activity?

Comment: When I click share, the Share menu appears (see image at the bottom http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/02/share-with-intents.html ) and sharing works. But I want to move my intent update from onPause to when the user clics on the share menu. The menu xml file contains a special attribute : android:actionProviderClass.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? It seems like this should be a common problem - I'm certainly struggling with it!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement OnShareTargetSelectedListener instead. It is called when a share target has been selected.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener.html